# How can I list all keyboard shortcuts / hotkeys and what they are bound to in Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, windows-10

Right now my "change virtual desktop" keyboard shortcut does not work on Windows 10. It is normally bound to ctl + ➡️ by Windows.

I have tried resolving the issue by guess and check to no avail. Further, I and other StackExchange users have had similar problems with VSCode, Windows, Internet Explorer, etc.

I would like a general method for listing keyboard shortcut / hotkey bindings on Windows so I and other can reliably diagnose any issue like this in the future. Command line solution is preferred, but a programmed or GUI solution is acceptable.

The process I'd like to follow is:

1. List all hotkey bindings on my Windows instance
2. Identify if there is a conflicting hotkey binding or if the root cause is different
3. De-conflict the hotkey binding
4. Profit

I do not want the solution of only using Safe Mode because it does not give me the precise information I want quickly. I do not want a guess and check solution. Windows OS knows what the hotkey bindings are, so there must be a way for Windows to tell me what they are, otherwise how would Windows know?

I have tried the following:

- Disabling possibly conflicting background applications
- Searching YouTube, Reddit, StackExchange, Google
- Reviewed the Microsoft Docs:

1. [How to Retrieve and Set a Hot Key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/-retrieve-and-set-a-hot-key) - didn't understand the code sample due to lack of Win32 C++ experience; code sample didn't solve my problem

2. [RegisterHotKey function (winuser.h)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerhotkey)
 - sets a hotkey, doesn't get it

3. [UnregisterHotKey function (winuser.h)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-unregisterhotkey)
 - unsets a hotkey, doesn't get it

4. [WM_GETHOTKEY message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-gethotkey)
 - didn't understand how to use

3. [WM_SETHOTKEY message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-sethotkey)
 - don't think this solves my problem

Comment: I have seen a freeware program that lists all registered hotkeys but I don't know how it works. There is no documented API to list them.

Comment: *"Windows OS knows what the hotkey bindings are, so there must be a way for Windows to tell me"* - That's incorrect, for two reasons: `1` A system can have features without providing a public API, and `2` the system doesn't actually know. An application could use a low-level keyboard hook or Raw Input to implement hotkey functionality, and the system simply wouldn't know what client code actually does. In fact, every hotkey implementation outside of `RegisterHotKey` is pretty much opaque to the system.

Comment: See here at the end of this thread: https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=69139 it will give you two ways to get hotkeys (w/o any 100% guarantee since apps can hook some Windows behavior).